# CSV import in SQL - Add new updated existing

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssms

Is there a way to use the existing Import features from SQL Server Manager, to import a CSV file and if the record (by primary key)exists update record and if it doesnt exist then insert or do i have to write custom scripts to do this?

Comment: Import means inserting things. *Updating* existing data isn't importing. If you want to update existing data, import the new data into a staging table and update the production table with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write something custom for this.   The import wizard cannot do this.